# wxPython binary created in pyinstaller creates ugly output on Fedora/RHEL

Tags: wxpython, rhel, pyinstaller, pango

I have searched far and wide for two weeks trying to solve my issue and nothing has done much good, so I'm at the end of my string here! I created a custom printer-selection app for my workplace in Python, and used pyinstaller to make a one-file executable, which I intend to distribute to all of our machines. The catch is that I use Linux Mint, but the lab machines are RHEL 6.3. I have tried several virtual machines including Centos 6.3 and Fedora 17, and both give me the same issue. The problem is that I get a bunch of "Pango-WARNING **" errors in the console and then my app comes up with square boxes instead of text.

my console output when running "test" application:

```
>(test:22258): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
>Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pk-gtk-module"
>Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
>
>./d00087.ps
>
>(test:22258): Pango-WARNING **: failed to choose a font, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderFc', script='latin'
>
>(test:22258): Pango-WARNING **: failed to choose a font, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderFc', script='common'
```

[image of output](http://i781.photobucket.com/albums/yy93/radial_2/Screenshotfrom2013-04-16180205_zps9f61e1db.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you didn't include the font files it wants when you packaged it up. Tell PyInstaller to include those or manually copy them in. Or tell wxPython to use a normal font. Looking those errors up points to Cairo having an issue. Maybe the RHEL doesn't have Cairo installed or is using a different version of Cairo.

Comment: Hmm I will check that. I didn't specify a font in the application at all, but since it bundles everything together into one meta-binary I can understand that.

Comment: I'm just thinking that PyInstaller is not bundling something up. I would run across something like this with py2exe on Windows where it wouldn't bundle up the images I needed.

Comment: I discovered that each system needs its own binary, so I solved the problem by running pyinstaller on the guest machine.

Comment: Well, that sucks. I wonder if you could make a RHEL version and a Centos version.